# Enable disable anchor, Jquery

Tags: jquery, click

Here is the html:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="http://xyz.com"><img src="./xyz.png"/></a></li>
    <li><a href="http://xyz.com"><img src="./xyz.png"/></a></li>
    <li><a href="http://xyz.com"><img src="./xyz.png"/></a></li>
    <li><a href="http://xyz.com"><img src="./xyz.png"/></a></li>

</ul>
```

If I click the second li it should go to the link but not if I click any other li. I have this code, I want to know a way to enable the default action.

```
 $(li[k]).click(function(){//increase the height});
 $(li[k]).find('a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to re-enable the default behavior of one of the links?

You can do that like this:

```
$(li[k]).find('a').unbind("click");
```

This will remove the click handler from the selected element, essentially returning it to its default behavior.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest something like the following:

```
 $(li[k]).click(function(){//increase the height});
 $(li[k]).find('a').click(function(e) {
        if ($(this).parent().index() != 1){
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
```

The way that this works is that if the `index()` of the clicked `li` element (based on its position among its siblings) is not equal to `1` (JavaScript arrays being zero-based, 1 is the second element in the array), the `e.preventDefault()` fires; otherwise (if the `index()` *is* equal to `1`) the default action is permitted.